# How to import data into master/replica structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, import, replication, mysql-backup

I have a file called `db.sql`; this file contains the data for one database. I want to import this data into a database called `db` in the newly established master/replica structure.

I used `mysql -u USER -p'PASS' db < db.sql` command to import the database into the master server. After import, The date was inserted into `master` server successfully but did not insert into the `replica` server. (But still, work without error)

I check the content of the `db.sql` file, which includes:

```
SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;

SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED='server-1:1-376,
server-2:1-2086154';

#end of the file
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

I know the reason for that is disabling `binlog`, yet I have three questions:

1. I have many backup files exported in this way; how to import them into my current `master` server, then it goes to the `replica` server. (I think If I remove those lines, it will fix my problem but is there anyways to do it directly by MySQL?)
2. For newly exported backups, how to prevent this issue in a way that can import directly? The below script produce the `db.sql` file.

```
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"STOP SLAVE" 2> /dev/null

mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN}  --single-transaction --quick ${DB_NAME}  2> /dev/null > ${OUTPUT_PATH}/db.sql

mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"START SLAVE"  2> /dev/null
```

3. The backup files come from different master/replicas with different `GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED`; is this causing any issues? If yes, how to solve it?

Comment: This question should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com, because it's about database operations, not a coding issue.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I asked the same question in dba.stackexchange.com but didn't get any attention, waht is why I asked here.

Comment: You should allow more than 16 hours to get a response on a volunteer site. Especially if you ask on a Saturday night on a holiday weekend! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html says:

> If you do not set the `--set-gtid-purged` option, the default is that
> a `SET @@GLOBAL.gtid_purged` statement is included in the dump output
> if GTIDs are enabled on the server you are backing up, and the set of
> GTIDs in the global value of the `gtid_executed` system variable is
> not empty. A SET `@@SESSION.sql_log_bin=0` statement is also included
> if GTIDs are enabled on the server.

This matches what you are seeing in your dump output.

A bit later, the same page says:

> The possible values for the --set-gtid-purged option are as follows:
>
> ...
>
> `OFF`
>
> `SET @@GLOBAL.gtid_purged` is not added to the output, and SET
> `@@SESSION.sql_log_bin=0` is not added to the output. For a server
> where GTIDs are not in use, use this option or `AUTO`. Only use this
> option for a server where GTIDs are in use if you are sure that the
> required GTID set is already present in `gtid_purged` on the target
> server and should not be changed, or if you plan to identify and add
> any missing GTIDs manually.

I recommend setting `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` when you run `mysqldump`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what about previous Backups that Backup in this style, is there any ways to skip them during importing? or I should remove mentioned lines manually?

Comment: Remove the lines manually.